# Extending structs with protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following piece of code. The protocols and extensions I've added don't seem to be doing quite what I expect. What am I missing?

```
struct foo {
  var getFoo: String
  var getBar: bar
  
  struct bar {
    var getBar: String
  }
}

protocol FooProtocol {
  var getFoo: String { get }
  var getBar: BarProtocol { get }
}

extension foo: FooProtocol {} // Type 'foo' does not conform to protocol 'FooProtocol'

protocol BarProtocol {
  var getBar: String { get }
}

extension foo.bar: BarProtocol {}
```

The problem in this code is the line `extension foo: FooProtocol {}`, where we're trying to say that, in effect `foo.getBar.getBar` should be a valid property. However, Xcode throws up a compilation error saying "Type 'foo' does not conform to protocol 'FooProtocol'.

I can fix this by changing the following:

```
protocol FooProtocol {
  var getFoo: String { get }
  var getBar: foo.bar { get } // instead of var getBar: BarProtocol { get }
}
```

However, it seems the line `extension foo.bar: BarProtocol {}` should mean `FooProtocol` doesn't care if we give it `foo.bar` or `BarProtocol`. What am I missing here?

@Drobs answer was correct. Here's a bonus question.

**BONUS**

Now suppose I need to implement another struct that conforms to `FooProtocol`. Neither of these approaches work. What's the fix?

```
struct FooImplementation: FooProtocol { // Type 'FooImplementation' does not conform to protocol 'FooProtocol'
  var getFoo: String
  var getBar: BarProtocol
}
```

Do I need to use some sort of `typealias` to achieve this?

Comment: I think you’re talking about something related to protocol associated type. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use an `associatedtype` in the protocol. In that case it essentially says give me a type that implements the protocol `BarProtocol`.

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype BarType: BarProtocol

    var getFoo: String { get }
    var getBar: BarType { get }
}

protocol BarProtocol {
    var getBar: String { get }
}

struct Foo: FooProtocol {
    var getFoo: String
    var getBar: Bar

    struct Bar: BarProtocol {
        var getBar: String
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! I added a bonus question to my original question. If I want to implement `struct FooImplementation: FooProtocol`, how can I achieve this in a generic manner?

Comment: You mean like this? `struct FooImplementation<T: BarProtocol>: FooProtocol {
  var getFoo: String
  var getBar: T
}

FooImplementation<Foo.Bar>(getFoo: "Foo", getBar: Foo.Bar(getBar: "Bar"))`